# Aggregation RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (Node.js, Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm facing problem while doing aggregation in mongoose but reaming all queries are working fine.

**service.js file:**

```
service.getAllDeviceRecentLatLng = async (req,res) =>{
    try{
        let condition = [
                            {
                                $match:{clientId: utility.removeQuotationMarks(req.query.clientId)}
                            },
                           {
                             $project:
                              {
                                 deviceId:1,
                                 recent: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$history", -1 ] }
                              }
                           }
                        ];
    const deviceTrackingHistory = await DeviceTrackingHistory.getAggregation(condition);
        logger.info('sending all DeviceTrackingHistory...');
        res.send({success:true, code:200, msg:"sending all DeviceTrackingRecentLatLng", data:deviceTrackingHistory});
    }catch(err){
        logger.error('Error in getting DeviceTrackingHistory- ' + err);
        res.send({success:false, code:500, msg:"sending all DeviceTrackingRecentLatLng Faild", err:err});
    }
}
```

**model.js file:**

```
DeviceTrackerHistoryModel.getAggregation = (query) => {
    return DeviceTrackerHistoryModel.aggregation(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! i did wrong in query declaration in my mode.js file, **aggregate** instead of aggregation.

```
DeviceTrackerHistoryModel.getAggregation = (query) => {
    return DeviceTrackerHistoryModel.aggregate(query);
}
```